# Kaltura Chromecast problems

Tags: cross-domain, chromecast, same-origin-policy, kaltura

We have a kaltura CE server and want to send a LIVE stream to Chromecast. We created a styled receiver app.
When we open the player and try to connect to a Chromecast device, we get this error:

Unsafe attempt to load URL https://dev.yyyyy.com/p/102/sp/10200/playManifest/entryId/0_f4wphewh/format/applehttp/protocol/https/uiConfId/23448172/a.m3u8?referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly9kZXYuY2xvdWR2aWRlby5jb20uY28=&playSessionId=eca13709-002a-256e-b1b2-dd83510aa455 from frame with URL https://www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/default_receiver/1.0/app.html?skin 1. Domains, protocols and ports must match

Chromecast refuses to load the manifest from dev.yyyy.com despite the fact that all the headers have been set.

Any help will be appreciated,

David Eusse

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stackoverflow :-) 
try adding CORS headers to the m3u8 following this document:
https://developers.google.com/cast/v2/mpl_player#cors

Comment: Thank you,
I already fixed the CORS problem but Chromecast refuses to play the HLS live stream...

Comment: I found the problem, Chromecast doesn't like relative URL manifests.